# Enter records interactively

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g
I need to enter data interactively in the following query
What is the input format?

```
Insert into tab_name values (&project_id, '&project_name', '&client_name');
```

Comment: What client are you using?  SQL*Plus?

Comment: Yes @jonearles I'm using sql Plus

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into tab_name values (:project_id, :project_name, :client_name);
```

Comment: I'm asking in what format the input has to be given
Im getting a not enough values error message

Comment: @user2808264 The problem is not with the input format, as you put it. In your case, the `not enough values` error indicates that the table you are trying to insert data into has more columns than values provided. You need to explicitly specify columns you are inserting data into `insert into table_name(col1, col2, col3) values(&val1, '&val2', '&val3')`.